# Why does Akka.Net F# API define actorOf2 but not actorOf3, actorOf4 etc.?

Tags: f#, akka.net, actor-model

I am studying F# Akka.Net API which is quite different from its C# counterpart because it tries to expose Akka functionality in an idiomatic manner. So it introduces a computational expression **actor** and a couple of helper functions **actorOf** and **actorOf2**:

```
let consoleWriterActor = 
        spawn myActorSystem "consoleWriterActor" (actorOf Actors.consoleWriterActor)
let consoleReaderActor = 
        spawn myActorSystem "consoleReaderActor" (actorOf2 (Actors.consoleReaderActor consoleWriterActor))
```

The **actorOf** is useful to spawn an actor that don't depend on additional actors, and **actorOf2** allows sending another actor as an argument for the actor being created as shown above.

This is clear, but I wonder what's so special with taking just a single actor as a parameter? Wouldn't defining **actorOf3**, **actorOf4** etc. help to send multiple actor parameters to an actor being created? For example, a C# generic Action<...> macro has definitions for up to 16 action arguments. Would it make sense to define several **actorOfX** functions? For example, the code from Akka.Net bootcamp that uses validation action looks like this:

```
let consoleWriterActor = 
    spawn myActorSystem "consoleWriterActor" (actorOf Actors.consoleWriterActor)
let validationActor = 
    spawn myActorSystem "validationActor" (actorOf2 (Actors.validationActor consoleWriterActor))
let consoleReaderActor = 
    spawn myActorSystem "consoleReaderActor" (actorOf2 (Actors.consoleReaderActor validationActor))
```

You can see that actors reference each other in chain: consoleReaderActor references validationActor and validationActor references consoleWriterActor. But what if I want consoleReaderActor reference both validationActor and consoleWriterActor? It doesn't look like this is possible using **actorOf** functions.

**UPDATE** Thanks to the answer from @Horusiath. I checked one of the lessons from Akka.Net bootcamp (F# version), and it is in fact possible to specify multiple actors when spawning a new one:

```
let a1 = 
    spawn myActorSystem "a1" (actorOf Actors.consoleWriterActor)
let a2 = 
    spawn myActorSystem "a2" (actorOf2 (Actors.consoleReaderActor consoleWriterActor))
let a2 = 
    spawn myActorSystem "a3" (actorOf2 (Actors.fileValidatorActor consoleWriterActor tailCoordinatorActor))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`actorOf2` is not sending any actors as an argument. Instead it exposes actor context to the user-defined function. While for simple sink-based actors it's not necessary - here `actorOf` is sufficient - it's required for any kind of more advanced work, like spawning child actors, scheduling and subscribing and publishing messages.

Comment: Thank you for the correction @Horusiath - yes, it's the exposure of actor context. But the question still remains: in the example above the context of a reader actor becomes aware of validation actor which in turn can use writer actor. What if I want use both validator and write from within the context of reader actor? Current API doesn't seem to offer such possibility.

Comment: In your question you've used example from akka-bootcamp. There is also an F# version of it, just checkout FSharp branch from github repository. Concerning passing actors, take a look at [Unit1 - lesson 4](https://github.com/petabridge/akka-bootcamp/tree/FSharp/src/Unit-1/FSharp/lesson4). I think, you'll find well described answer there.

Comment: Thanks again, I'll checkout lesson 4. Looks like I missed that out.